# How to find all the characters used in a particular column in a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Having inherited a database with various string columns in various tables, I'm adding some validation into the code that references the database in order to validate the user data which feeds into these columns. Before I do this I wanted to find out which characters are already used in the columns so I have some idea of how to validate future data.

For example product names in a product table:

```
CREATE TABLE Products 
(
    [prod_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [prod_name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
)
```

So I have

```
CREATE TABLE #letters (letter char(1));

DECLARE @POS INT
SET @POS = 1

WHILE (@POS <= (SELECT MAX(LEN([prod_name])) FROM [Products])) 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #letters 
        SELECT SUBSTRING([prod_name], @POS, 1) FROM [Products]

    SET @POS = @POS + 1
END

SELECT DISTINCT letter, CAST(letter AS binary) 
FROM #letters 
ORDER BY letter

DELETE FROM #letters
```

This is quite clunky and slow, any suggestions for a neater solution?

Thanks

Comment: A `WHILE` is most certainly going to be a slow method; SQL is a set based language and so will be significantly faster at set based methods. I would use a Tally solution (such as [NGrams8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams)) to split the columns into single characters first, possibly `INSERT` that data into an indexed temporary table, and then `SELECT DISTINCT` the letters.

Comment: It seems odd to base validation on "what's already there" for something as potentially flexible as a product name. Just because (e.g.) there are currently no `è` characters in there doesn't mean `Gruyère` should be prohibited. Is there any reason you feel like you must prohibit things, instead of just allowing the full range of Unicode? And if there are such reasons, wouldn't those be valid independent of what's in there now?

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert agree this is not a great approach in general, however the fields concerned are entirely internal and the contents made up by the client. They would like the validation of the user data but are rather slow in letting me know what characters they would like to allow or not, so I thought I would get some idea ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will split all of the characters in the column into rows in the CTE, then I've added the counts by character as well.  Not sure what your data volume is like, but I tested this against a wide column in a table with almost 1 million rows and the query took under a minute to run.

```
drop table if exists #products
create table #products (prod_name nvarchar (50) NOT NULL)

insert into #products (prod_name)
values ('product1'),('product2'),('widget1'),('widget2')

;WITH split_products
AS (
    select substring(a.prod_name, v.number+1, 1) as charact
    from (select prod_name from #products b) a
    join master..spt_values v on v.number < len(a.prod_name)
    where v.type = 'P'
    )
select charact, count(*)
from split_products
group by charact
order by charact
```

Comment: Great - much quicker than my solution - thanks. I also like the count(*) feature.